# ORMLite error on insert with autoincrement key

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, ormlite-servicestack

I have the following `MVC 5` `Model`:

```
[Schema("dbo")]
[Alias("map")]
public class Map {
    [PrimaryKey]
    [Alias("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Alias("name")]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    //others

}
```

The `id` attribute on the table is a `primary key autoincrement`.

I need the `Id` to perform update operations but this prevents me to insert new entries.

This `update` works:

```
var res = dbConnection.Update<Map>(map);
```

While this `insert` does not:

```
var res = dbConnection.Insert<Map>(map, selectIdentity: true);
```

I get this exception:

> Cannot insert explicit valuefor identity column in table 'map' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: So, what's the value of `map.Id`?

Comment: It doesn't matter on insert, because I need the DBMS to set that according to the current increment value

Comment: It does matter, because if it's non-default (i.e. not `0`), the ORM will try to include it in the insert statement.

Comment: The error I get is about "you're not allowed to set id explicitly", no matter what the value is....

Comment: Even when it's 0? Can you verify that?

Comment: Wait a sec, I'll try

Comment: I can confirm that the exception is raised even passing 0

Comment: Shouldn't you also add a `[AutoIncrement]` attribute on the Id property?

Comment: It works! Thank you! Write it as an answer so I can set that as solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[AutoIncrement]` attribute instructs ORMLite to omit the attributed field from the INSERT field list.

So apply it to the Id property:

```
[PrimaryKey]
[AutoIncrement]
[Alias("id")]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

And its value will be ignored when inserting or updating that entity.